# avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264) returns null

Tags: android, ffmpeg, x264, avcodec

I am building an android application which will encode image captured from camera preview and later decode it. I am using ffmpeg library to encode and decode. To build static library with x264 I have used this tutorial. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22605641/ffmpeg_android/main.html. As a source code of ffmpeg if I use the one downloaded from the link given in tutorial I can built it but can't build library if i use source code downloaded from here git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg. I have built library in ubuntu and using it in windows 7 in Eclipse. As I need only h264 encoder and decoder I have used following code for ffmpeg, slightly modified from tutorial.

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=~/Documents/android-ndk-r8e
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86
PREFIX=/home/android-ffmpeg

function build_one
{
    ./configure --target-os=linux --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-asm \
    --arch=arm \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --disable-stripping \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --enable-nonfree \
    --enable-version3 \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-gpl \
    --disable-doc \
    --enable-avresample \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --enable-avcodec \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-encoder=libx264 \
    --enable-encoder=libx264rgb \
    --enable-decoder=h263 \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-decoder=svq3 \   
    --enable-zlib \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --extra-cflags="-I/home/android-ffmpeg/include -fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/home/android-ffmpeg/lib"
make -j4 install
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavfilter/libavfilter.a libavresample/libavresample.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog -lx264 --warn-once --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}

build_one
```

After building library I have been able to build android ndk. A little part of my JNI code is here.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_testjava_TestjniActivity_initencoder(JNIEnv* env,jobject obj){

    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
      __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "debug", "not found");                
       return -1;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

When I run my java source code that calls initencoder() I get -1 as return value and logcat prints "not found". That means avcodec_find_encoder() returns null and if condition is being ok. I don't know what's wrong. Why this function is returning null? I have searched a lot but did not find any solution that could guide me to right direction. some says to use avcodec_init(). But ndk-build command fails and shows error saying undefined reference to 'avcodec_init()'. I have started with library build because I thought may be I am doing wrong from the first stage. Did I make any mistake in library building like not enabling things that I should? Please help me here. This is kind of urgent for me.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains a specific question.  This will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. As far as I know, `avcodec_register_all()` should have taken care of it, but it has not. Works just fine on Ubuntu, but does not work on Android. Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: The same issue.Is anyone solve?

Comment: Seems h264 is only a decoder, not an encoder.

Comment: Having the same issue on Android, with h264 compiled as an encoder.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem: avcodec_find_encoder returns NULL;

## Possible causes:

1. libx264 something went wrong during compile or configuration process.
2. libx264 has not been packaged into apk or loaded properly.

My case, it was both. I had "--enable-libx264" in configuration option, but had not provided paths to android compatible libx264 library and include directories, so the library had been compiled without x264 support.
Hope this will save someone's time.

## Solution

After compiling x264 with the appropriate toolchain and making them available to ffmpeg at ffmpeg compilation time by setting --extracflags and placing self-compiled x264 libs and includes in jni folder, it stopped returning NULL at least.

My ffmpeg build script:

```
NDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

ADDI_CFLAGS="$ADDI_CFLAGS -I${NDK}/sources/x264 -I${NDK}/sources/x264/android/arm/include -L${NDK}/sources/x264/android/arm/lib -DANDROID -I${NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/system/include"
# -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"

ADDI_LDFLAGS="$ADDI_LDFLAGS -L${NDK}/sources/x264/android/arm/lib"
#--extra-cxxflags='-Wno-multichar -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'

function build_it {
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX    \
    --disable-static    \
    --enable-shared     \
    --disable-doc       \
    --disable-ffmpeg    \
    --disable-ffplay    \
    --disable-ffprobe   \
    --disable-ffserver  \
    --disable-avdevice  \
    --disable-doc       \
    --disable-symver    \
    --cross-prefix=$CPREFIX \
    --target-os=linux   \
    --arch=arm      \
    --enable-cross-compile  \
    --enable-gpl        \
    --enable-libx264    \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT  \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG


    make clean
    make
    make install

    echo "build done run make install"
}


build_it
```

My x264 build script:

```
#Android related

NDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

export PATH="$PATH:$TOOLCHAIN/bin"

#PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/FFmpeg/lib/pkgconfig" 

function build_it {
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --bindir=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/bin \
    --enable-static \
    --host=arm-linux \
    --enable-pic \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --enable-shared \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
}
build_it
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reusing the function

```
avcodec_register_all()
```

before

```
avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
```

The functionality is deprecated, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
av_register_all(); already calls avcodec_register_all() inside it.
```

So don't put  avcodec_register_all();